# Question on noun modification 茶色い目のキレイな少女

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, parsing

The following is from a worksheet on noun modification:

> 文があいまいにならないように気をつけましょう。
>
> > 茶色い目のキレイな少女
>
> → 茶色い目がキレイな少女（キレイな茶色の目をした少女）
> → 茶色い目の、キレイな少女（茶色い目で、ルックスがキレイな少女）
> → 茶色い、目のキレイな少女（目がキレイで、肌が茶色い少女）

I'm not 100% about what is being shown here but I think it's saying that 茶色い目のキレイな少女 is a bit ambiguous and the three sentences that follow aren't as ambiguous?

Answer (score 4):

Right, the sentence

> 茶色い目のキレイな少女

is ambiguous and may be parsed in the following ways

1. > 茶色い目のキレイな　少女
2. > 茶色い目の　(キレイな　少女)
3. > 茶色い　(目のキレイな　少女)

---

1. In the first parsing, 茶色い目がキレイ modifies 少女, where が has become の through *ga*-*no* conversion

   > A young lady, who has beautiful brown eyes.

   This interpretation is forced by not using *ga*-*no* conversion

   > → 茶色い目がキレイな少女
2. In the second parsing, キレイな modifies 少女 and 茶色い目の modifies キレイな少女

   > A beautiful young lady, who has brown eyes.

   This parsing is suggested by inserting a comma

   > → 茶色い目の、キレイな少女
3. In the third parsing, 目のキレイな modifies 少女 and 茶色い modifies 目のキレイな少女.

   > A young lady with beautiful eyes, who is brown.

   This parsing is suggested by inserting a comma

   > → 茶色い、目のキレイな少女

---

In English we have

> a beautiful brown-eyed young lady

which captures the ambiguity between (1) and (2), where it's not clear whether the eyes are beautiful or the young lady herself.